# GRPC Client - Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, grpc, netty

I am writing a GRPC client in Kotlin / Spring Boot. When I connect to the provided GRPC server, I get the error:

```
io.grpc.StatusException: INTERNAL: http2 exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asException(Status.java:550)
    at io.grpc.kotlin.ClientCalls$rpcImpl$1$1$1.onClose(ClientCalls.kt:296)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:468)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:432)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:465)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:562)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:743)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:722)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Caused by:
io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:109)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.verifyFirstFrameIsSettings(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:353)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:247)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:453)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

I don't own or have control of the GRPC service.

When I use grpcurl, I can connect without an error:

```
grpcurl -insecure xxx-yyy.k8s.dev.zzz.com:443 list
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
zzz.xxx.v2.internal.account.ABCAPI
```

I've read other posts on this error which seem to suggest a problem with the server configuration. But since I am able to grpcurl it, I wonder if I have an error in my client config.

```
@Configuration
class GrpcClientConfig() {


    @Bean
    fun grpcClient(grpcChannel: Channel) = GrpcClient(
        channel = grpcChannel
    )


    @Bean
    fun grpcChannel(channelCredentials: ChannelCredentials): Channel = NettyChannelBuilder
        .forAddress("xxx-yyy.k8s.dev.zzz.com", 443, channelCredentials)
        .build()

    @Bean
    fun grpcChannelCredentials(): ChannelCredentials = InsecureChannelCredentials.create()


}
```

Any idea why grpcurl works, but my Kotlin client does not?

Answer (score 1):

Decoding `485454502f` from hex to ascii:

```
❯ echo '485454502f' | xxd -r -p
HTTP/%
```

Looks like your Kotlin client attempts to make HTTP/1.1 connection, not HTTP2.
See similar issue described here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2905.